# Can't create Docker Swarm because of connection failure

Tags: docker-swarm

1. Target: Creating a Docker Swarm
2. Condition:

   - Host A: Ubuntu 23.10
   - Host B: Mac Sonoma 14.1.2
3. Operation:

   - In Host A:

     ```bash
     docker swarm init
     ```
   - In Host B:

     ```bash
     docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-3o2m78qf57hy2zikfx8p2yc7hrn63edlmlixwrq7bh28xws7zx-9oirn0wh3mbrdui3kcwytl560 192.168.65.9:2377
     ```
4. Error:

   ```bash
   Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error:
   desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.65.9:2377: connect: no route to host"
   ```
5. What I've done so far:

   - Installed firewalld on Ubuntu Host A, but for unknown reason it caused system crash. I guess this is because Ubuntu 23.10 doesn't support firewalld anymore.
   - Use ufw command to open communication port on Ubuntu Host A, but it doesn't work.
6. Asking for help: I saw other people can easily run the "docker swarm join" command in the tutorial. Why I got this problem? Any one can help me out? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that both are connected to a local network (connected inside a network)

You need to connect machines together verify that by ping (if you are using a firewall then ping ICMP packets wont work). do a curl request from A to B

2. Check firewall status `ufw status` if its status: inactive then its not a problem else disable the firewall(DISCLAIMER: may become a security issue) or Open only specific ports like 2376, 4789, 2377, 7946.

```
ufw allow 7946/tcp
ufw allow 7946/udp
ufw allow 2376/tcp
ufw allow 4789/udp
ufw allow 2377/tcp
```

`sudo ufw reload`

Answer (score 1):

You need to open several ports for the communication (On `A` as well ass `B` hosts):

As [Docker documentations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts) says:

- Port 2377 TCP for communication with and between manager nodes
- Port 7946 TCP/UDP for overlay network node discovery
- Port 4789 UDP (configurable) for overlay network traffic

Furthermore:

- Port 2376 TCP for secure Docker client communication.

Set UFW config (Or disable the UFW as you mentioned in your question):

```bash
ufw allow 22/tcp
ufw allow 2376/tcp
ufw allow 2377/tcp
ufw allow 7946/tcp
ufw allow 7946/udp
ufw allow 4789/udp
ufw reload
ufw enable
systemctl restart docker
```

You can check the IpTables configuration as well based on this documentation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-ubuntu-16-04

BUT, The "Docker for Mac" uses different networking as Linux based and that can cause turbulence in Docker Swarm. Here is a ticket for it: https://github.com/moby/swarmkit/issues/1146#issuecomment-231412874

Based on the above ticket the Mac can run only single-node Swarm right now. (I didn't find fix for it)